# Vault error in windows while configuring Oracle Database Plugin

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to test for the first time Vault with Oracle Database on windows.
I made first steps of the tutorials but while I execute

```
vault write D:\Applications\vault_1.4.0_windows_amd64\oracle-database-plugin sha256="DEDDFSQ23EF" command=vault-plugin-database-oracle
```

I have got an error

```
Error writing data to D:\Applications\vault_1.4.0_windows_amd64\oracle-database-plugin: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/D:%5CApplications%5Cvault_1.4.0_windows_amd64%5Coracle-database-plugin

Code: 404. Errors:

* no handler for route 'D:\Applications\vault_1.4.0_windows_amd64\oracle-database-plugin' here
```

I can't understand what's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did to fix this:
Inside Vault directory, I have created plugins directory where I have dwnloaded the right oracle plugins. Then I have used this command on cmd or Powershell on windows

```
vault write sys/plugins/catalog/database/oracle-database-plugin sha256="8A8ABE17E7A2A75BD871RE43D" command=vault-plugin-database-oracle
```